# Rails pagination in API using Her, Faraday

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, faraday

I've been trying to figure this out all day, and it's driving me crazy.

I have two rails apps, ServerApp and ClientApp. ClientApp gets data from ServerApp through an API, using the Her gem. Everything was great until I needed pagination information.

This is the method I am using to get the orders (this uses kamainari for pagination and ransack for search):

```rb
# ServerApp
def search
  @search = Order.includes(:documents, :client).order('id desc').search(params[:q])
  @orders = @search.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per])

  respond_with @orders.as_json(include: :documents)
end
```

It returns an array of hashes in json, which Her uses as a collection of orders. That works fine.

```rb
# Response
[
  {
    "client_id": 239,
    "created_at": "2013-05-15T15:37:03-07:00",
    "id": 2422,
    "ordered_at": "2013-05-15T15:37:03-07:00",
    "origin": "online",
    "updated_at": "2013-05-15T15:37:03-07:00",
    "documents": [
      { ... }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

But I needed pagination information. It looked like I needed to [send it as metadata with my json](https://github.com/remiprev/her/issues/82). So I change my response to this:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    render json: { orders: @orders.as_json(include: :documents), metadata: 'sent' }
  end
end
```

This does indeed send over metadata, so in my ClientApp I can write @orders.metadata and get 'sent'. But now my orders are nested in an array inside of 'orders', so I need to use  @orders.orders, and then it treats it like an array instead of a Her collection.

After doing some reading, it seemed sending pagination info through headers was the way a lot of other people did this (I was able to get the headers set up in an after_filter using [this guide](http://metabates.com/2012/02/22/adding-pagination-to-an-api/)). But I am even more lost on how to get those response headers in my ClientApp - I believe I need a Faraday Middleware but I just am having no luck getting this to work.

If anyone knows how I can just get this done, I would be very grateful. I can't take another day of banging my head against the wall on this, but I feel like I am just *one vital piece of info away* from solving this!

Comment: evt. this might also be an issue for the Her project. You can open an issue there, and see if you get feedback from the project maintainers

Comment: I had considered posting it to the Her github page, but I thought this was more a misunderstanding on my part and not an issue on their part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and solved it by adding my own middleware and rewriting the "parse" and "on_complete" methods without that much hassle and avoiding the use of global variables.

Here's the code:

```
   class CustomParserMiddleware < Her::Middleware::DefaultParseJSON
      def parse(env)
         json = parse_json(env[:body])
         pagination = parse_json(env[:response_headers][:pagination_key]) || {}
         errors = json.delete(:errors) || {}
         metadata = json.delete(:metadata) || {}
         {
           :data => json,
           :errors => errors,
           :metadata => {
              :pagination => pagination,
              :additional_metadata => metadata
            },

     end

      def on_complete(env)
        env[:body] = case env[:status]
           when 204
             parse('{}')
           else
            parse(env)
         end
      end
    end
```

then, you can access the pagination as follows:

```
    model = Model.all
    model.metadata[:pagination]
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally got this working. The trick was to use a global variable in the faraday on_complete - I tried to find a better solution but this was the best I could do. Once again, I got the header code from [here](http://metabates.com/2012/02/22/adding-pagination-to-an-api/). Here's the full guide to how to get pagination working with Her:

First, on my server side, I have the Kaminari gem, and I pass `page` and `per` as params to the server from the client. (This is also using ransack for searching)

```rb
def search
  @search = Order.order('id desc').search(params[:q])
  @orders = @search.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per])

  respond_with @orders.as_json(include: :items)
end
```

My client makes the request like so:

```rb
@orders = Order.search(q: { client_id_eq: @current_user.id }, page: params[:page], per: 3)`
```

Back on the server, I have this in my ApiController (app controller for api):

```rb
protected
  def self.set_pagination_headers(name, options = {})
    after_filter(options) do |controller|
      results = instance_variable_get("@#{name}")
      headers["X-Pagination"] = {
        total_count: results.total_count,
        offset_value: results.offset_value
      }.to_json
    end
  end
```

In the server orders_controller.rb, I set the pagination headers for the search method:

```rb
class OrdersController < ApiController
  set_pagination_headers :orders, only: [:search]
  ...
end
```

Now to receive the headers we need a Faraday middleware in Her on the client.

```rb
# config/initializers/her.rb
Her::API.setup url: Constants.api.url do |c|
  c.use TokenAuthentication
  c.use HeaderParser # <= This is my middleware for headers
  c.use Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded
  c.use Her::Middleware::DefaultParseJSON
  c.use Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
  c.use Faraday::Response::RaiseError
end

# lib/header_parser.rb
# don't forget to load this file in application.rb with something like:
# config.autoload_paths += Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "*.rb")].each { |l| require l }

class HeaderParser < Faraday::Response::Middleware
   def on_complete(env)
    unless env[:response_headers]['x-pagination'].nil?
      # Set the global var for pagination
      $pagination = JSON.parse(env[:response_headers]['x-pagination'], symbolize_names: true)
    end
  end
 end
```

Now back in your client controller, you have a global variable of hash called $pagination; mine looks like this:

```rb
$pagintation = { total_count: 0, offset_value: 0 }`
```

Finally, I added Kaminari gem to my client app to paginate the array and get those easy pagination links:

```rb
@orders = Kaminari.paginate_array(@orders, total_count: $pagination[:total_count]).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])`
```

I hope this can help someone else, and if anyone knows a better way to do this, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

- You can pass header options to Faraday when setting up the connection, see the docs at http://rubydoc.info/gems/faraday/0.8.7/Faraday/Connection:initialize
- Sometimes it helps to do a `curl` request first, esp. use `-vv` option for verbose output where you will see all headers. (Maybe you can attach some log outputs from the Server too)
- You can use e.g. `clogger` (http://clogger.rubyforge.org/) do monitor header information on the Rails server side

Comment: I am actually already adding headers in Faraday using the middleware that is posted on Her's github page. The problem is I don't fully understand how to write the on_complete middleware to get the headers being sent back from the API, and then make them available to my controller. And I am using Postman Chrome extension, and the headers are there - I just am not sure how to use them! The furthest I've seen a guide go in describing what to do with headers involved just writing to a log.